# Codeigniter, not echoing validation_error();

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I created a new controller `questions.php` which is not the default controller. I have already loaded the `form_validation` library but it did not echo out the validation errors when I submitted empty fields from my form. Other questions in SO seems to be completely unrelated to my situation.

Below is my `questions.php` controller. BTW I have only posted the necessary bits of the class controller.

```
<?php
class Questions extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        $this->load->library("form_validation");
    }

    public function user_logged_in(){
     $this->load->library('../controllers/main');

     $obj = new $this->main();
     $status = $obj->logged_in();
          if($status){
          return true;
        }else{
         return false;
      }
   }
    public function question_validation(){
        if($this->user_logged_in() == false){
            redirect('main/index');
        } else{
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('input_title','Title','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Question Details','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('vidya','Tags','required');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
                $this->load->library('../controllers/main');
                $obj = new $this->main();
                $getUserData = $obj->getLogged_userData();
                $userdata = array(
                    'uservalues' => $getUserData
                );

                $this->load->view('view_header'); 
                $this->load->view('view_nav',$userdata);
                $this->load->view('log_user/user_second_nav');  
                $this->load->view('question_posts/post_questions');
                $this->load->view('view_footer');
            } else{
                echo "form has been submitted";
       }
    }

}
?>
```

The form page in view called `post_questions.php` which is shown below,

```
<?php
    $this->load->helper("form");
    echo validation_errors();
    echo form_open('questions/question_validation');
?>
<p><h2>Question title</h2></p>
<p><input type="text" name="input_title" id="input_title"   
placeholder="what is your question please be specific and clear"></p>

<p><h3>Now Describe in detail!</h3>
<p><textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10px" cols="86px"></textarea></p>
<p><h3>Tags</h3></p><p><input type="text" id="vidyagames" name="vidya"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="post" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Before this, the questions controller was giving me error like undefined property `Questions::$form_validation` so I added a `__construct()` and now it wont echo out the form validation errors.

Can you help me because probably the form isn't being submitted at all. 
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Looks like its perfect, the problem i found is here: $obj = new $this->main(); When you load it as a library, you already create an instance of it as $this->main, use it like this: $getUserData = $this->main->getLogged_userData();

Comment: NO everything went wrong, now it is showing Undefined property: Main::$test_model at core/Model.php. I have never touched the core/model and it is showing me an error. And I have already autoloaded in config/autoload.php $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); I dont know what is going on

Comment: @Anindya. Hey, I found only found the source of the error but not the solution. It is that my user_logged_in() method was already loading a library, so maybe it couldn't load the form_validation helper class. Do you happen to know the solution to it please, thank you.